# Background handleopenurl with Runkeeper api

Tags: ios, objective-c, background, fetch, openurl

I have a problem with Runkeeper Api background handleopenurl. When app is running foreground there are no problems with it and I can get calorie data from RK.

But I need to run this calorie fetch when the app is backgrounded.

This code is what works when app is backgrounded:

```
- (NSURLRequest *) connect
{
    NSLog(@"runkeeper connect");
    NSString *_authURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?client_id=%@&redirect_uri=%@&response_type=code&state=0", [auth_url absoluteString], client_id, [redirect_url absoluteString]];
NSURLRequest *_request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:_authURL]];

return _request;
}
```

But after this it wont work anymore.

So it should send the url to handleopenurl, which is in appdelegate, and then it fetch the calorie data.

And here is my handleopenurl:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url
{

RunKeeper *runkeeper;    
runkeeper = [RunKeeper getRunKeeper];

// parsing code here
if(url){

    [runkeeper parseCodeFromURL:url];
    [runkeeper fetchToken];

    [runkeeper fetchUser];
    [runkeeper fetchFitnessActivites];

    [self.second_view showInput];

    return true;
}

return false;

}
```

However handleopenurl is not called when app is backgrounded. What should I do? I have tried many background methods but none of them seems to be working.

All in all: Runkeeper api calorie data fetch works when app is foregrounded but it wont fetch the calorie data when app is backgrounded. I think the problem is with handleopenurl.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood what you're trying to do but `application:handleOpenURL` is the method that gets called when some OTHER app is trying to `openURL:` YOUR app. In any case, if your app is backgrounded you can not use `openURL:` to get data from RunKeeper, this only works when your app is in the foreground.

Comment: Ok thanks for your answer!
Do you know is there any options that I could use for this problem?